# How to use an already declared type under a new namespace?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to use an already declared type under a new namespace.
The code below gives me an error `declaration or statement expected`. What am I missing?

```
interface MyInterface {
  myProp: string;
}

declare namespace MyNamespace {
  export MyInterface; // this line errors
}
```

I found a solution, but it doesn't feel like the right one. What do you think?

```
interface MyInterface {
  myProp: string;
}

declare namespace MyNamespace {
  export interface MyInterface extends MyInterface {}
}
```

The reason I'm doing this is that I have components in my app and I want them to export types under a single namespace `MyNamespace`, so that I could use the type anywhere in the app without having to import them individually.

P.S The code above doesn't work as expected. The exported types are not visible globally. So, I ended up doing this (which is not a solution at all)

**./translator/types.d.ts**

```
declare namespace AppTypes {
  export interface Dictionary {
    [key: string]: {
      [key: string]: string
    }
  }
}
```

**./config-service/types.d.ts**

```
declare namespace AppTypes {
  export interface Config {
    [key: string]: boolean;
  }
}
```

**anywhere in the app**

```
const dictionary: AppTypes.Dictionary = {...}
const config: AppTypes.Config = {...}
```

Comment: Can you move the `declare namespace` to the top of your file or do you style rules forbid it? I recommend looking at the `index.d.ts` files of popular packages like `firebase` and `express` for inspiration

Comment: Hey! Thank you! Yeah, I should probably look for an answer in some high quality packages. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it by this way

```
 declare namespace MyNamespace {
    export interface MyInterface {
        myProp: string;
    }
  };
```